# While com Href - PHP

Tags: php

Caros;

Tenho este código:

```
<?php

    $sql = "select * from tabela where codsegur = '7562315'";

    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    $count = $stm->rowCount();

    if ($count > 0) {
       while($row = $stm->fetch())  {
           echo "<a href=caminho/".$row['caminho']."></a>";
       }
    }
?>
```

A variável `$row` recebe o retorno do SQL acima, e o `array` caminho seria o caminho onde estaria o arquivo. Neste caso, queria concatenar o `href` juntamente com o caminho e gerar o link do arquivo em minha pagina para download. Resumindo, ao acessar a página e digitar o código (7562315) no formulário, apresentar o arquivo em questão, cujo arquivo está com seu caminho setado na `array` (caminho). Para não precisar por o formulário todo, setei o código direto no SQL para dar o retorno que eu preciso.

Quando faço este processo, nada acontece, e não gera erros. Quando eu dou um `echo` no `$row['caminho']`, aparece o caminho que está setado no banco de dados.

Alguém pode me auxiliar no que/onde estou errando?

Obs: A conexão ao banco de dados está Ok.

Grato.

Comment: Não faltou o conteúdo da tag `<a>`? Você preencheu apenas o `href`.

Comment: Nossa, que falta de atenção bizarra. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro está na falta abertura de aspas para o parâmetro `href`. O correto seria:

```
echo "<a href='caminho/".$row['caminho']."'></a>";
```

Deixando o conteúdo dentro do parâmetro `href` entre aspas simples.

Comment: Na verdade, não estava aparecendo, era devido eu não ter colocado o conteudo entre as tags do href. Por isso nada aparecia, nesta tag coloquei um click aqui e deu certo. Falta de atenção minha. Abraços.

Comment: Boa. De qualquer forma é necessário incluir as aspas como o @David indicou. Eu tinha escrito uma resposta igual a esta e só depois notei que ele já havia respondido, possivelmente foi ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Digo que é necessário incluir as aspas para evitar erros que vão estragar seu HTML futuramente.

Comment: Boa, obrigado pela dica, inseri no meu código. Já está td resolvido. Abraços.